# how to find the largest sum in a 20x20 array

Tags: java, arrays, sum

here's what I have to do

1. Create a program that instantiates a 20x20 array of integers.
2. Populate that array with random numbers from 0 to 100.
3. Write a program that will search the array and find the 3x3 box of numbers within the larger array that has the largest sum.

here's what I have
I keep getting an error rand I don't know how to fix it 
package codes;

```
public class BoxArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int LENGTH = 20;
        int WIDTH = 20;
        int[][] array = new int[LENGTH][WIDTH];
        for (int x = 0; x < LENGTH; x++) {
            array[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 20) + 1;
            for (int y = 0; y < WIDTH; y++) {
                array[y] = (int) (Math.random() * 20) + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The array is");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        int largestSum = 0;
        int addressX = 0;
        int addressY = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you _try_ to put in the final `for` loop which gave an error?  And what error was it?  The error in the _given_ code would presumably be that `largestSum = 0;` is unlikely to always be true.

Comment: *I keep getting an error* ... which error? Would you mind adding a call stack, @HOODIENICK, sir?

Comment: `array` is a 2D array, and so `array[x]` is a 1-dimensional array, and you cannot assign an int to it. You need two indices for this to work: `array[i][j] = someInt;`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for helping but where do I put the array[i][j] = someInt;